# Split content in Nokogiri when tags are encountered

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

Given the following part of an HTML page, I want to be able to treat "us" and "John" as separate.

```
            <div id="ad-description" class="c-clear c-word-wrap">

Room for rent in Sydney.
<br/><br/>For more information please contact us<br/>John :- 0491 570 156<br/>Jane :- (02) 5550 1234</div>

    <!-- google_ad_section_end(name=description) -->
        </div>
```

When using Nokogiri to access the ad-description node, and then call `content` on that node, I get `usJohn` as part of the resulting string:

```
document = Nokogiri::HTML(text)
ad_description_xpath = './/div[contains(@id, "ad-description")]'
ad_description_nodes = document.xpath(ad_description_xpath)
ad_description_node = ad_description_nodes.first
ad_description_node.content # "...please contact usJohn :- ..."
```

How can I have Nokogiri either return a string with whitespace of some sort between "us" and "John", or have "us" and "John" in separate strings?

Ideally, the approach taken will be able to handle will handle any tags within the node, without the code I write having to mention specific tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `text()` node selector will select text nodes, which will give you each section of text in its own Node. You could then use `map` to get an array of strings:

```
document = Nokogiri::HTML(text)
# Note text() added to end of XPath here:
ad_description_nodes = document.xpath('.//div[contains(@id, "ad-description")]/text()'

strings = ad_description_nodes.map &:content
```

With your sample data, `strings` will now look like:

```
["\n\nRoom for rent in Sydney.\n", "For more information please contact us", "John :- 0491 570 156", "Jane :- (02) 5550 1234"]
```

As you can see you might get some extra leading or trailing whitespace, as well as possibly some nodes consisting solely of whitespace, so you’ll likely need some more processing. Also this would miss any text that isn’t a direct child of the div, e.g. if there is some text in `strong` or `em` tags. If that’s a possibility you could use `//text()` instead of `/text()`.

Answer (score 3):

You can call [`#children`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/ElementContent:children) to get the children of `ad_description_node`, and then filter text node with [`text?`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/sparklemotion/nokogiri/Nokogiri/XML/Node:text?). This way you will have an array of text nodes inside `ad_description_node`:

```
ad_description_node.children.select( &:text? ).map( &:content )

# [
#   [0] "\n\n  Room for rent in Sydney.\n  ",
#   [1] "For more information please contact us",
#   [2] "John :- 0491 570 156",
#   [3] "Jane :- (02) 5550 1234"
# ]
```